# How to deal with IE when writing Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This is kind of a two-part question.

Why does IE require so much special treatment when handling Javascript? And are there any tricks, resources, and/or systems you have picked up for making your js IE-compatible, besides Firebug lite?

Comment: What special treatment are you referring to? I can't think of that many JavaScript issues, especially not if you're using a library like jQuery. The visual (CSS) differences are much, much more extreme

Comment: Reading other peoples' js code I've seen comments regularly that say something like, "required to make IE work" or "IE chokes on _x_ so here's _y_" I guess there's not a LOT of these special casesout there but they're definitely there and I'm not sure when to expect I will need to code around them.

Comment: @Pekka - having a library like jQuery handle the special treatment issues for you doesn't mean the issues don't exist. I agree about the CSS stuff though.

Comment: IE requires special treatments bcoz in some cases IE follows its own standards but don't worry sometime those guys come back and make changes as in other standard-compliant browsers :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standardised libraries like J-query so you don't have to jump through all the hoops yourself works on the javascript side!

Also Yahoo User Interface (YUI) is good for making websites look extremely similar over different browsers. Their [Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssgrids/) library works really well.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking at YUI now. The thing is I'm doing a lot of custom code over Google maps and I'm not sure jQuery can do everything I need it to, though I am already using it for certain functions.

Comment: YUI is wonderful :) It takes a little time to get used to how to code the layout, but the results are worth it in the end!

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the js bit is a lot like jQuery.

Comment: I've never used the google maps API so I can't comment, but jQuery is a very standardised library so I wouldn't be surprised. Thanks for accepting my answer Artur :)

Comment: jQuery doesn't override any core JS functionality like some other frameworks so it should cause any problems with Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please elaborate little what you're referring to?

JavaScript in it's core is have mainly been the same the last 10 years. If you're worried about older IE versions (IE6-7) you can remain calm. IE6 was released with JavaScript 1.5 support so all JS code should run fine. Mozilla has a very good JS ref document at [their MDC site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference). At the bottom of each page there's usually a list of what version of each browser that supports that specific function.

However the difference between browser usually lies in the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) implementation or event handling. Where properties may have different names, at the top of my head these properties mainly are related to element/scroll positions.

To find the correct property to use, check in the developer tool (Firebug in IE, Developer Tools in Webkit or Developer Toolbar in IE) for that browser to find what you are looking for. If you're unsure set at JavaScript breakpoint in your code using the `debugger;`keyword or send something to the console using `console.log()`. In IE Developer Toolbar is available from IE8+ (I think).

Most of these problems are already resolved in the major JavaScript frameworks like jQuery, MonoTools and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The two main "special treatment" things that come to mind are:

1. Events. Including assignment of event handlers, the way the event object is made available to the handler function, and some of the properties of the event object. See this page for more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html
2. Ajax. Use of `XMLHttpRequest` versus `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`.

Most everything else should be fine.

You can write yourself some (relatively) simple helper functions to get around these issues, or use a library like jQuery that normalises the differences for you. If you do write it yourself, be sure to test for *feature support* rather than try to test for which browser - see this (long) article for an explanation: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/ (I'm sure there are shorter explanations around but I can't be bothered finding one.)

Comment: Hah no worries, I'll do the research I just needed a point in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you using jquery in your page then you can check for ie with this code

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '6.0') {
     //do IE specific code
}
```

This code will only run when the user browser will be IE 6.0 or you leave this condition